# adding events from google calendar programmatically..?

Tags: iphone, calendar

I want to add events to native calendar from google's calendar programmatically ..i have and program that can fetch events from google calendar and show them in table view..how can i add these events to iphone's native calendar one by one...?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a "thinking out of the box" suggestion, I assume just using [Google Mobile Sync](http://m.google.com/sync) to do all this for you is out of the question? I can tell you from bitter experience (implementing the calendar part of Google Mobile Sync) that converting between different calendar representations isn't fun.

(Unfortunately I don't have any experience on the iPhone itself, so I can't offer any advice beyond that...)

Comment: we can also do that but i want to add it from my applications so i have to do it programmatically....

Comment: @Kuldeep: Ah well - fair enough :(

Comment: i have one more issue...how to access the public calendar on google..via api..?

Comment: @Kuldeep: Yes, you'd use the GData API. I thought you'd already got code to fetch it though?

Comment: yes i got it...but i need to fetch the public calendars..without login..?can i do so..? if yes how?